# replace carriage return and new line from sql server in javascript

Tags: javascript, sql-server, dojo

I've got varchar data from SQL Server returned to javascript as JSON where I'm trying to remove carriage return + linefeed with br.  When I query my data in SQL Server I can see I have CHAR(13)CHAR(10) characters.  My javascript code I've tried is below: (taEmail is a dijit/form/SimpleTextarea):

```
var data = this.taEmail.get("value");
var regxp = /\r\n/g;
var data2 = data.replace(regxp, "<br\>");
```

also tried:

```
 var data = this.taEmail.get("value");
 var data2 = data.replace("CHAR(13)(CHAR(10)", "<br\>");
```

Any ideas how I can make this work?  I suppose I could do it on the SQL server end, but would prefer javascript

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps `var data = dojo.byId("taEmail").value` - CHAR(13) is that not BASIC or VBScript or something?

Comment: the data variable is getting populated -- you're probably right about CHAR -- I think its a function SQL server uses to convert control characters to string -- so that wouldnt work on the javascript side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a simple test in the console window of the browser and it works.
below is my code.

```
var data = "line end\r\n";
/*
console output for data >>>
"line end
"
*/
var data1 = data.replace(/\r\n/g,"<br>");
 /*   
console output for data1 >>>
"line end<br>"
*/
```

Comment: This worked when I pulled the value of data from the json instead of the textarea widget -- I guess the textarea widget changed the encoding somehow?